# Advice on best way to show consulting experience in Careers profile

Tags: support, jobs

I've been a consultant for over 7 years and operate as a company (albeit a one-man-band at this stage). In the `Experience` section of my Careers Profile, I want to list myself as being a consultant (as my company) for that time, but I also have some engagements that last 12 months or more that it would be really great to include those in the `Experience` section too (i.e. to name drop).

Therefore, I'm heading in the direction of listing experience in this order:

- Principal Consultant @ My Company, 2006 to Now
- Title 1 @ Company A, 2012 to Now
- Title 2 @ Company B, 2011 to 2012
- Title 3 @ Company C (Project), 2009 to 2009

So does anybody have any advice on how it's best to show the experience gained on projects/assignments as a consultant?

Does anyone think it matters that the experience appears non-continuous?

Would it best to put a leading statement in the `Responsibilities` section of each that makes it clear this was an assignment or project as a consultant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a fairly typical situation.  Exactly what you are proposing works great and adding that line about doing this as a consultant is the common cure.

From a search algorithm perspective, gaps in the last 5 years do negatively affect ranking a small amount per tag on the current algorithm.  That being said, it's typically better to break it up to give the employers searching a more complete view of your overall skillset.

A little more insight: based on our current search interface, most candidate searches are executed by adding more and more filters until the list gets small enough to review the entire result set, and then they typically look at all the profiles and message the ones they like the best.  Since our search is effectively boolean in this sense, as long as you have the skills, you will remain in the result set, and since they review the entire final list, being a few slots down doesn't really affect your chances of getting messaged nearly as much as the content of your profile.

Comment: Thanks for the info on how the searching operates. In essence, there will be no gap in the last 5 years as there'll be an overlap instead. The "now" situation is that I'm `Principal Consultant @ My Company` and `Title 1 @ Company A`. This approach isn't what I do on LinkedIn, but I've often wondered whether I should.